# Insert to particular location in Oracle DB table?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

Suppose I have a table containing the following data:

```
Name | Things
-------------
Foo  |   5
Bar  |   3
Baz  |   8
```

If I want to insert a row, so that the final state of the table is:

```
Name | Things
-------------
Foo  |   5
Qux  |   6
Bar  |   3
Baz  |   8
```

Is this possible?

I understand we don't typically rely on the order of rows in a table, but I've inherited some code that does precisely that. If I can insert to a location, I can avoid a significant refactor.

Comment: You have code that inserts a row at a particular physical location in an Oracle table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you say, you can't rely on the order of rows in a table (without an ORDER BY).

I would probably refactor the code anyway - there's a chance it will break with no warning at some point in the future - surely better to deal with it now under controlled circumstances?

Answer (score 3):

I would add a FLOAT column to the table and if you wanted to insert a row between the rows whose value in that column was 7.00000 and 8.000000 respectively, your new row would have value 7.50000.  If you then wanted to insert a row between 7.00000 and 7.50000 the new row would get 7.25000, and so on.  Then, when you order by that column, you get the columns in the desired order. Fairly easy to retrofit. But not as robust as one likes things to be. You should revoke all update/insert permissions from the table and handle I/O via a stored procedure.